# Use parent setter while overriding child in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, setter

Im trying to replicate some java code in kotlin in an idiomatic way. In particular, I want to use the parent setter while overriding the child setter for future uses. In java I could do:

```
public class Parent() {

    public View rootView;

    void setRootView(View view) {
        this.rootView = view
    }
}


public class Child() extends Parent() {

    private FrameLayout layout;

    public Child(View rootView) {
        super.setRootView(rootView)
    }

    @Override
    void setRootView(View view) {
        layout.addView(view)
    }
}
```

When I set the rootView in the Child constructor, I would be using the parent's setter method, but the next time `setRootView(View view)` method is called, it would use the Child setter method.

Is it posible to get the same functionality in Kotlin?

Comment: You should never call open functions of the same class from the constructor in Java or Kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

It´s sounds like a code smell. Calling an overridable method from a constructor could result in failures or strange behaviors when instantiating a subclass which overrides the method.